# Why is SSMS Version 18.8 storing question mark characters instead of Chinese characters in NVarchar columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, nvarchar

I am working on a big table in SSMS. Some columns are of datatype `Nvarchar` to store mixed characters of English and Chinese.

However, the Chinese characters are being stored as `????`.

How can I read all Chinese characters properly?

Comment: **HOW** are you storing those Chinese characters? If you use T-SQL and string literals to insert the value, you **MUST** use the `N'.....'` prefix for your string literals so they are properly handled as **Unicode** string literals

Comment: Yes, I am using T-SQL and I am aware of using N '...' while inserting Unicode string in the table but here I am not inserting new data . The table is super big and is already in Server.

Comment: Well, those Chinese characters that are already showing up as `????` cannot be "saved" - they must have been mishandled somewhere along the way and converted to non-Unicode - an irreversible and destructive conversion, no way to "reverse" that, I'm afraid